# Extension method to compare all fields including IEnumerable

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I am trying to write an extension method that compares objects based on their fields.

I have this:

```
public static class MyExtensions 
{
    public static bool FieldsEquals(this object o, object other) 
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(o, other))  
            return true;

        if (o == null || other == null || o.GetType() != other.GetType()) 
            return false;

        foreach (var f in o.GetType().GetFields()) 
        {
             // is this a correct test ???
             bool isEnumerable = f.FieldType != typeof(string) && 
                                 typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType);

             if (!isEnumerable) 
             {
                 if (!f.GetValue(o).Equals(f.GetValue(other))) 
                     return false;
             } 
             else 
             {
                // convert both to IEnumerable and check if equal 
             }
        }

        return true;
     }
}
```

I am struggling with the case of the field being a collection; I need to detect that case and then check the collections are the same (same number of elements and `f.GetValue(o)[i] == f.GetValue(other)[i]`.

Any help?

Comment: _"I am trying to write a generic extension method"_ - Where?

Comment: in my solution ?

Comment: You are just using objects and reflection. No [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).

Comment: @SeM Maybe "generic" and "Generics" are different in the OP's context?

Comment: @UweKeim then probably he should use [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/). :)

Comment: I've come across this situation when doing work where im trying to check for duplicates in deserialized data, basically its a form of 'Deep equality', and its not simple to achieve. There are a lot of edge cases that havent been considered

Answer (score 2):

Okay, like others already mentionend. There are a lot of edge cases..

I would recommend to use recursion for this kind of problem.

This method should also check arrays or lists that contain objects:

```
public static bool FieldsEquals(this object o1, object o2)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(o1, o2))
        return true;

    if (o1 == null || o2 == null || o1.GetType() != o2.GetType())
        return false;

    if (o1 is IEnumerable enumerable1 && o2 is IEnumerable enumerable2)
    {
        var enumerator1 = enumerable1.GetEnumerator();
        var enumerator2 = enumerable2.GetEnumerator();

        while(enumerator1.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!enumerator2.MoveNext())
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!enumerator1.Current.FieldsEquals(enumerator2.Current))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var f in o1.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            var val1 = f.GetValue(o1);
            var val2 = f.GetValue(o2);

            if (val1 == null || val2 == null) continue;
            if (val1 is IEnumerable e1 && val2 is IEnumerable e2)
            {
                if (!e1.FieldsEquals(e2))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!val1.Equals(val2))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to make the following check just after the while loop: if (enumerator2.MoveNext()) { return false; }. If you don't do that, then you will get incorrect result when, say, enumerable1 is empty and enumerable2 has some items.

Comment: Also, I would make this method generic, so that I have some type information in advance. I don't think the following is correct in a general sense: if (o1 == null || o2 == null || o1.GetType() != o2.GetType()) return false;. To me and to the C# language, if obj1 == null && obj2 == null, then these objects are equal, i.e. obj1 == obj2 is true.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, there are a lot of problems here. What if the types are basic types (like int) or Structs (datetime,etc). What if the enumerable fields contain classes not basic types? or the properties are classes?

See this question for some guidelines on deep equality: [Compare the content of two objects for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375996/compare-the-content-of-two-objects-for-equality)

All that said, here is my crack at the code you mentioned

```
public static bool FieldsEquals(this object o, object other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(o, other)) return true;
    if (o == null || other == null || o.GetType() != other.GetType()) return false;

    foreach (var f in o.GetType().GetFields())
    {
        bool isEnumerable = f.GetValue(o).GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable));// but is not a string
        if (!isEnumerable)
        {
            if (!f.GetValue(o).Equals(f.GetValue(other))) return false;

        }
        else
        {
            var first = ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)f.GetValue(o)).Cast<object>().ToArray();
            var second = ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)f.GetValue(other)).Cast<object>().ToArray();
            if (first.Length != second.Length)
                return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
            {
                if (first[i] != second[i]) //assumes they are basic types, which implement equality checking. If they are classes, you may need to recursively call this method
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I am not looking for deep equality, I assume all fields which are basic types or objects (that is are not collections) know how to equal themselves, would you solution then hold ?

Comment: also is there a way to use sequenceEqual ??

Comment: SequenceEqual would be fine, but if the array contains objects, then it would fail. You would need to add code into the for loop to test for arrays of 'Objects' (basically rejig this method so that if its not a basic type, string or datetime, recurse over the method)